# getting started ex 4.3 follow instructions but doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the "Getting started" section on the ruby on rails site  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. I am at section 4.3 and trying to make "Hello, rails!" appear on the index page. however I simply get an error. what am I doing wrong?

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index 

Showing C:/Sites/Mysite/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised: 
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Extracted source (around line #7): 
5
6
7
8
9
10

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Rails.root: C:/Sites/Mysite

Comment: Care to show the exact error that you're getting, like a log?

Comment: Is it working when is not the root?

Comment: that is the error that I copy pasted.

Comment: how do I make it not the root?

Comment: what is a log and how do I show it?

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
 
  root 'welcome#index'
end

Comment: the above is the code that causes the problem . in particular this line: 
  root 'welcome#index'.  when I comment this line out I get the " yay youre on rails" screen.  when I include this line I get an error page with the following title: ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index 
 what does this mean and how can I solve it?. this line is supposed to make "Hello Rails!" appear.